# switch to DAX from the Excel convention of prefixing the row value with "@"

Tags: sum, powerbi, dax

I have a general ledger table with 43,000 rows (FCT_GL_Details) which has transactions that I want to consolidate into a trail balance (FCT_GL_TB) grouped by Branch, Account, Subaccount, finYear in "yyyy" format, finMonth in "mm" , PeriodID (being FinYearFinMonth in "yyyymm", and then I want to sum the NettAmt. I have created a referenced table and grouped by the above. What I now need is two opening balances, a life-to-date (LTD_Opening) and a year-to-date (YTD_Opening) based on same financial year.

The Excel equivalent:

```
LTD_Opening = sumifs([NettAmt],[Periodid],"<"&[@[PeriodID]],[Branch],[@[Branch]],[Account],[@[Account]],[Subaccount],[@[Subaccount]])
```

and YTD would include

```
... ",[FinYear],[@[FinYear]])
```

With the filtering how do I switch from the Excel convention of prefixing the row value with "@"?

Example:
[image]

Comment: Can you add some sample data and your expected output from them?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. Comments are ephemeral & for asking for clarification & identifying problems. You can post your own answer in an answer post. After a minimum wait time you can accept it. [answer] [Help]

Comment: Again: Social & meta commentary do not belong in posts. [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/266284) [When should I edit posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) [Help] See Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se].

Answer (score 0):

Although I have some confusion on your opening balance consideration, you can achieve your required output with couple of **Custom Column** and **Measures** given below-

First of all lets create a Date **Custom Column** to check dates using value from FinYear and FinMonth for all months as below-

```
first_date_of_month = DATE(your_table_name[finyear],your_table_name[finmonth],1)
```

Now create this below 2 more **Custom Column** where from we can check the row belongs to Opening date regards to corresponding Branch and FinYear.

```
is_initial_opening_of_branch = 

var current_row_branch = your_table_name[branch]
var current_row_first_date_of_month = your_table_name[first_date_of_month]

var check_first_balance_of_branch =
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(your_table_name),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[branch] = current_row_branch
        && your_table_name[first_date_of_month] <= current_row_first_date_of_month
    )
)

return IF(check_first_balance_of_branch = 1,1,0)
```

```
is_initial_opening_of_finyear = 

var current_row_branch = your_table_name[branch]
var current_row_finyear = your_table_name[finyear]
var current_row_first_date_of_month = your_table_name[first_date_of_month]

var check_first_balance_of_branch_finyear =
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(your_table_name),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[branch] = current_row_branch
        && your_table_name[finyear] = current_row_finyear
        && your_table_name[first_date_of_month] <= current_row_first_date_of_month
    )
)

return IF(check_first_balance_of_branch_finyear = 1,1,0)
```

**Now** lets create your required 2 measure as below-

```
ltd_opening = 

var current_row_branch = MIN(your_table_name[branch])
var current_row_first_date_of_month = MIN(your_table_name[first_date_of_month])

return 
CALCULATE(
    sum(your_table_name[nett]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[branch] = current_row_branch
        && your_table_name[first_date_of_month] <= current_row_first_date_of_month
        && your_table_name[is_initial_opening_of_branch] <> 1 
    )
) + 0
```

```
ytd_opening = 

var current_row_branch = MIN(your_table_name[branch])
var current_row_finyear = MIN(your_table_name[finyear])
var current_row_first_date_of_month = MIN(your_table_name[first_date_of_month])

return 
CALCULATE(
    sum(your_table_name[nett]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[branch] = current_row_branch
        && your_table_name[finyear] = current_row_finyear
        && your_table_name[first_date_of_month] <= current_row_first_date_of_month
        && your_table_name[is_initial_opening_of_finyear] <> 1 
    )
) + 0
```

Here is the final output-

[image]

Comment: mkRabbani - thanks for trying but you totally missed the nature of the question, i.e. grasping row context and the purpose of the @symbol in excel. This was not about how to calculate an opening balance conceptually, but how to get the current row and the point is you don't have to. Also, why not simply as "X" and use the "SUMIFS" Calculate(really does complicate DAX - it really is like trying to rewrite the SUM function to act like the SUMIFS. I did clearly state I am struggling with the "@" concept and even you said you don't get the issue ... someone else may have actually helped.